# Input texbox spacing HTML

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in Angular:

```
<div class="center" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <label class='input-w' for='start-date'>
      <span class='label'><b>Start Date</b></span>
      <input type="date" id="start-date" name="start-date" style="width: 200px;">
    </label>
    
    <label class='input-w' for='end-date' >
      <span class='label'><b>End Date</b></span>
      <input type="date" id="end-date" name="end-date" style="width: 200px;">
    </label>
    
</div>
```

It produces this output:

[image: Output Screenshot]

I can't figure out how to separate the labels and boxes. I need them to be on the same line with some space between them so the start is midway left and the end is midway right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some css style info into your code, add margin to your code

Add a `<style>` section into your code, if you haven't already, and put a `margin` attribute to your `label` and add how much ever margin you want.

It should go something like this

```css
.input-w {
    margin: how much ever margin you want;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flex!

On the center class, you could have a center--horizontal class which uses flex to align all content in a row. You might need to rejig your elements so that the inputs are outside the labels.

Flex by default is a row so you don't need to define this

Here's a good resource for flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```
.center--horizontal {
  display: flex;
}
```

**Extra**: You might need to add some margin to one of the elements but that's just down to how much margin you want. Whenever I do anything with flex, I tend to put the children in divs (sometimes this isn't neccessary if you only outputting one element) if you are putting multiple elements together, this just makes it easier to to group elements together